# Append values to variable

Tags: powershell, foreach

```
$SamAccount = 'samaccountname'
$Groups = "DL1;DL2;D3;Grp1;Grp2;Grp3"
$Paramsgroup = $Groups.Split(';')
#$Paramsgroup

    foreach ($Group in $Paramsgroup) {
        $GroupSID = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like $Group})
        #Start-Sleep 5
        try {
        Remove-ADGroupMember $GroupSID -Members $SamAccount -Confirm:$false
        }
        catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        #Write-host $ErrorMessage
              }
    }
```

I have a script that removes certain groups from a user. I want to store somewhere only the list of groups that have been removed. 
Tried `$variable+= output` , but not getting the desired output. Please assist

Comment: It's usually better to test for membership before removal rather than simply try to remove all groups and produce errors for those which don't apply.

Comment: I tried testing the groups which the user is part of but it takes a lot of time to test the membership.

Comment: You're kind of doing it backwards. If you already know the groups you potentially want to remove the user from, then use "Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership" to get the user's groups and store them in an object, then you can simply compare/match each one that with your group list by name. You can then do Remove-AdGroupmember with the distinguishedName of the matched groups (that you already have from Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership). You *already* have your list of deleted groups for output (since that's what you're processing).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it as an array, then it will work like you want.

```
[System.Array] $variable += $output
```